# How to preserve object's materials in fluid sim?

Tags: rendering, materials, fluid-simulation

I have an object with multiple materials that I want to turn into liquid but once I make fluid simulation it just turns into liquid with default liquid material (glass + volume). I want to liquify that object and keep it's materials as the fluid simulation is happening. How do I do that?